# Return the repeat items in ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to build function to return object in jquery like this:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li data-year="2011" data-month="1">Jan</li>
  <li data-year="2011" data-month="2">Feb</li>
  <li data-year="2012" data-month="3">Mar</li>
  <li data-year="2012" data-month="4">Apr</li>
  <li data-year="2012" data-month="5">May</li>
</ul>
```

Search for li item, find data-year and return an object with count of equal items, like that 
{2011: 2, 2012: 3}

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to add new attributes to `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function obj(ul) {
    return {
               2011: $('li[data-year="2011"]', ul).length,
               2012: $('li[data-year="2012"]', ul).length
           }
}

console.log(obj($('ul')))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2n7t/2/

Update:

```
var obj = {};

$('ul li[data-year]').each(function(){
   var year = $(this).data('year');
   obj[year] = obj[year] ? obj[year] + 1 : 1
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2n7t/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i dont know wath data-year are in the li.
I need search for all data-year, and return number and name of repeats.

Comment: Want work, i expect obj: {2011: 2, 2012: 3}
Your code return me:
2011: "undefined[object Object]"
2012: "undefined[object Object]"

Comment: @user1663812 No, have you checked the fiddle? This happens when your li tags don't have a data-year attribute.

Comment: I don´t see the console output in fiddle, but in my local machine want work.

Comment: Forgot the console is the same, browser! I will try in my local machine.

Comment: I believe the problem became because i use coffescript, and the bug come from this expression obj[year] =  obj[year] ? obj[year] + 1 : 1

You dont know coffescript or another way to write the some expression?

http://jsfiddle.net/x2n7t/5/

Comment: I solve the if stament with this way, obj[year] = if obj[year] then obj[year] + 1 else 1

Really work! Many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
var arr = [];
$('ul li').each(function(){
    var y = $(this).attr('data-year');
    if($.inArray(y,arr) < 0)
        arr.push(y);
});
// You build the Array with the List of Items..
//console.log(arr);

// Build the Object Here..

var obj = {};
$.each(arr, function(i){
    var y = arr[i];
    obj[y] = $('ul li[data-year="'+ y + '"]').length;
});
console.log(obj);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/v2YNp/)